# Dead code warning when setting color dynamically

Tags: flutter, dart, dead-code

I'm trying to make buttons that turn grey after having been pressed. I read up on how to do this. The best way I could find is to set the material color with a ternary operator and then change the condition for that in a `setState(() {})` block:

```
  Container vehicleButton(IconData icon_, String text_, {required Function onClickAction}){
    const double buttonSizeX = 200;
    const double buttonSizeY = 100;
    const double iconSize = 60;
    const double buttonTextSize = 15;

    const double buttonMargin = 5;
    
    Color buttonColor = const Color(0xff2196f3);
    const Color iconColor = Color(0xffffffff);
    const Color buttonTextColor = Color(0xffffffff);

    bool pressed = false;

    return Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: buttonMargin, right: buttonMargin, top: buttonMargin, bottom: buttonMargin), child: SizedBox.fromSize(
      size: Size(buttonSizeX, buttonSizeY), child: Material(color: pressed ? Color.fromARGB(255, 143, 143, 143) : buttonColor, child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          pressed = true;
        });
        onClickAction();
      },
      child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <Widget>[
          Icon(icon_, color: iconColor, size: iconSize),
          Text(text_, style: TextStyle(fontSize: buttonTextSize, color: buttonTextColor)),
    ])))));
  }
```

However, I'm getting a warning that the code after the ? in my ternary operator is dead code. And indeed, the button does not turn grey after pressing.

I thought maybe the values of Material are final and cannot be changed, but this wouldn't explain why all the examples I could find on the internet use this method.

Comment: Your ternary expression contains dead code because at that point, the local variable `pressed` is known to always be `false`.  You perhaps do not intend for `pressed` to be a variable local to the `vehicleButton` function.

Comment: How would you suggest to do it?

Comment: you have to explicitly check condition at runtime 'pressed == true?' which I suggested in answer. If you do not check, then because of compile time check, it always becomes false causing dead code.

Comment: @Anteino As I already said, you probably want `pressed` to not be a local variable.  Currently the button's `onTap` callback will have no ultimate effect: it will modify a local variable that will never be read again.  If `vehicleButton` is a method on an `State`, then make `pressed` a member on that `State`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```dart
Container vehicleButton(...) {
  bool pressed = false;

  return Container(
      ...
      child: SizedBox.fromSize(
          ...
          child: Material(
              color: pressed ? Color.fromARGB(255, 143, 143, 143) : buttonColor,
              child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      pressed = true;
                    });
                    onClickAction();
                  },
```

The Dart analysis tools are correctly reporting that `Color.fromARGB(...)` is dead code because the conditional ternary operator checks the state of the *local* `pressed` variable, which at the time it's checked, is *always* `false`.  Although the `onTap` handler sets `pressed = true`, it's setting the state of the local `pressed` variable, which will never be read again.

You likely intend for `pressed` to be a *member* variable of whatever `State` class contains the `vehicleButton` method.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a SizedBox I suggest you to use the buttons provided by flutter dev: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons

A simple try you can give is:

```
RaisedButton(
      child: new Text('Attention'),
      textColor: Colors.white,
      color: pressColor ? Colors.grey : Colors.blue, //Choose your personal colors
      onPressed: () => setState(() => pressColor = !pressColor), //change the button colors
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that you have to define your variable build(BuildContext context)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).